# Published persistent property - Should I use FMyPersistent.Assign(Value) or FMyPersistent:= Value?

Tags: delphi, properties, delphi-xe2, variable-assignment

When I'm building a custom component, I may implement published persistent properties. For example...

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyPersistent: TMyPersistent;    
    ...
  public
    ...
  published
    property MyPersistent: TMyPersistent read FMyPersistent write SetMyPersistent;
    ...
  end;
```

Note that the procedure `SetMyPersistent` is not here yet, that's where the next step comes in. I right-click this object and select "Complete Class at Cursor" (or `Shift + Control + C`) to invoke the code completion. When it automatically creates this property setter, it automatically puts the assignment code in...

```
procedure TMyComponent.SetMyPersistent(const Value: TMyPersistent);
begin
  FMyPersistent := Value;
end;
```

Now it's nice that it went ahead and completed this assignment for me. However, in normal cases, I've always grown accustomed to using...

```
procedure TMyComponent.SetMyPersistent(const Value: TMyPersistent);
begin
  FMyPersistent.Assign(Value);
end;
```

In cases where the property is a type such as `String` or `Integer`, then a direct assignment is the proper way to do it. But when implementing a published property of a `TPersistent`, isn't it the correct method using `TPersistent.Assign`?

What's the essential difference between using these two assignment mechanisms? Because if using `TPersistent.Assign` is the appropriate thing to do, then the code completion has a slight flaw - that is, assuming that `FMyPersistent := Value` is considered "wrong".

Comment: Are you asking whether you should Assign the content to an object you own, versus replace an object with another, and leak the previous one? I think you can figure that out on your own! If your object creates a FMyPersistent in its constructor and frees it in its destructor, then use Assign, otherwise, if it's a weak reference, and you don't own the object or free it, use variable FField :=  Value.  it's all about ownership.

Comment: Well my original question title was something like "Why does Complete Class at Cursor do a direct assignment of a published persistent property?" But I changed it because it didn't really match the core of the question. It's just really peculiar why that particular instance would trigger the IDE to write some improper code, only for you to have to replace it. I was wondering why the IDE would do such a thing, but of course that question would have been considered off-topic.

Comment: @Jerry It doesn't matter what the IDE thinks. It's got no brain. Do you want a reference or a copy? That's the question. You decide.

Comment: The IDE doesn't have any way to know who you intend to own an object versus get a copy of its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `Assign`. That's why you have a property setter in the first place. If you were to directly overwrite the field, you wouldn't need a setter. Overwriting it would leak the original object you created in the constructor. You'd also notice access violations in the IDE when you modified the property in the Object Inspector.

Code completion puts the same code in every setter it creates. For properties that have additional work to do before ultimately storing the value in a field, so the field-storage statement is correct. The IDE doesn't know what you really want.

Comment: On the other hand, if it's not expected to to assign a new persistent in its place, then there really shouldn't even be a setter in the first place, just a read-only persistent property.

Comment: You're welcome to do that, but then the property won't be editable in the Object Inspector. The Object Inspect doesn't present read-only properties, and when it assigns a property, it always does so as though through an assignment statement. It doesn't call `Assign`. So, if you want your property editable the same way `TFont` and `TPen` properties are editable, you need to provide a setter, and you need to call `Assign` (or the moral equivalent) in it.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is wrong in some cases, such as when property is a TDataset and is not an object I own.

Comment: I don't really see where my answer is wrong, @Warren, but don't be coy: correct it, please.

Answer (score 3):

The question you should be asking yourself is - who owns the objects involved?  If your component creates and owns `FMyPersistent` then use `FMyPersistent.Assign(Value)` to copy values from `Value` into `FPersistent`.  If `FMyPersistent` merely points at an external object that someone else owns then use `FMyPersistent := Value` instead.